# How to solve inequalities where the $x$ term appears inside the argument of multiple different functions?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

We're asked to study the sign of the following function:

$$\frac{x(\ln{x}+1)^2 - 2(\ln{x}+1)^2 - \frac{4}{x(\ln{x}+1)}}{(x(\ln{x}-1)^2)^2} \geq0,$$

in which the $x$ variable appears both outside and inside some natural logarithms. I tried rewriting the entire function in respect to $\ln{x}$, but that clearly didn't help. How would you study the sign of this function?

Comment: at first i would plot the left-hand side of your inequality

Comment: is it $\ln(x)+1$ or $\ln(x+1)$?

Comment: It is $\ln{(x)}+1$.

Comment: Note the LHS is defined only if $x > 0$ and $x \not \in \{\frac1e, e\}$.  Next, the denominator is always positive, so we may ignore it.  Then we only have to consider 
$$x \ge 2+\frac4{(\ln x + 1)^3}$$

LHS is increasing to $ \infty $, while RHS decreases to $2$, so there is some $ x_0$ beyond which this always holds true.  It is also possible to see that there is some interval close to zero where this will hold true - though getting more exact may need numerical computing.